# harmon.ie limitations when copying large numbers of emails into SharePoint

Tags: limit, harmon.ie

Does Harmon.ie for Outlook have any limitations when copying emails into SharePoint libraries? It seems to fail when copying around 1000 items but I have not been able to locate any documentation that states the Harmon.ie Outlook add-in limits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are customer I answered to the email you sent to harmon.ie support.

----- Jean